# React variable value not replaced in api call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use UseParam to get the id, i am trying to place it inside of my API request however when i console.log it the actual value doesn't go inside rather the text itself.

vesselComponents.js :

```
function VesselComponents() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const api = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        // here
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${id}`
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  console.log(api);
  const { components, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.components
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchComponents()(dispatch);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems) => {
    return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
      let children = undefined;
      if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
        children = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
      }
      return (
        <TreeItem
          component={Link}
          to={`./info/${treeItemData.id}`}
          key={treeItemData.id}
          nodeId={String(treeItemData.id)}
          label={treeItemData.name}
          children={children}
        />
      );
    });
  };
  const DataTreeView = ({ treeItems }) => {
    return (
      <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      >
        {getTreeItemsFromData(treeItems)}
      </TreeView>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="components-container">
      <div className="components-items">
        <DataTreeView treeItems={components} />
      </div>
      <div className="component-detail">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VesselComponents;
```

This is how the console.log look like :

```
async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default().get( // here
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${id}`);
      return res.data;
    } catch (err…
```

Also if i wanted to make this call rather in my slice how would i go about exporting this specific ID that changes so i can use it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you actually log the function, not the return value.

I suppose you want to fetch the maintenance id as the component mounts. I advice you to use `useEffect` for this case.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; // above the component's class declaration

// and inside your component

const [api, setApi] = useState(null); // null by default

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchMaintenance = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          // here
          `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${id}`
        );
        return res.data;
      } catch (error) {
        throw Error(error);
      }
    });
  };

  fetchMaintenance()
    .then((api) => {
      setApi(api);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

And by that you can use the value of `api` anywhere you like.

For example to log it

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(api);
}, [api]);
```

or to render it on your view

```
return (
    return (
    <div className="components-container">
      {JSON.stringify(api)}
      <div className="components-items">
        <DataTreeView treeItems={components} />
      </div>
      <div className="component-detail">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```